# MessageBox закрывается сам по себе

Tags: wpf, messagebox, c#

Есть такой код:

```
private void TestConnection()
{
    try
    {
        Connection.Open();
    }
    catch (MySqlException ex)
    {
        string error = string.Format("Ошибка: {0}\n\n{1}", 
            ex.Message, "Открыть окно настроек для ввода новых параметров?");
        var result = MessageBox.Show(error, "Ошибка соединения", 
            MessageBoxButton.YesNo, MessageBoxImage.Error);

        if (result == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
        {
            var wind = new SettingsWindow();
            wind.ShowDialog();

            BuildConnectionString();
        }
        else
            Environment.Exit(0);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (Connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            Connection.Close();
    }
}
```

Так вот, в большинстве случаев этот код работает отлично и все ок, но иногда MessageBox закрывается самостоятельно и в result приходит MessageBoxResult.No, в чем проблема, и как этого избежать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я не создаю SplashScreen через Build Action, у картинки BuildAction - Resource, а объект SplashScreen вызываю явно (он в сборке WindowsBase). Ну и, когда объект создан, его можно запомнить в какую-нибудь переменную и прибить.

Answer (score 3):

Проблема кроется в стандартном WPF-овском SplashScreen'e. Именно он убивает все окна при своем закрытии. Подробнее: WPF splash screen dismisses dialog.

Comment: Для борьбы с этой проблемой я обычно явно закрываю SplashScreen перед тем, как мне требуется диалоговое окно.

Comment: Не подскажете как?